# FactoryBot association load existing ActiveRecord model

Tags: factory-bot

Given the following Rails models...

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_category
  after_initialize :do_stuff_based_on_category

  def do_stuff_based_on_category
    # things that reference `project_category` object
    project_category.foo_bar
  end
end

class ProjectCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects

  def foo_bar
    # ...
  end
end
```

The number and content of `ProjectCategory` records is fixed: the test setup utilizes the same records that exist in production. Consequently I want my `Project` factories to utilize explicit, persisted `ProjectCategory` objects (*not* factories).

However I cannot get my `Project` factories to pick up the `ProjectCategory` record, even though a normal `new` call works just fine:

```
obj = Project.new project_category: ProjectCategory.find(1)
obj.project_category
# => #<ProjectCategory:0x007f851de8c9a8

# (Older syntax, running FactoryGirl 4.5.0)
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    project_category { ProjectCategory.find(1) }
    # ...
  end
end

obj = FactoryGirl.build(:project)
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `foo_bar' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/project.rb:7:in `do_stuff_based_on_category'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in my usage of an association within an `after_initialize` hook.

From the [factory_bot documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Custom_Construction) (bolding my emphasis):

> For maximum compatibility with ActiveRecord, the default initializer
>   builds all instances by calling `new` on your build class **without any
>   arguments.** It then calls attribute writer methods to assign all the
>   attribute values.

Unlike a direct call to `Project.new`, which would include attributes, factory_bot by default passes in nothing and sets attributes after the fact.

Fortunately, factory_bot exposes the initializer to address these types of scenarios.

> If you want to use factory_bot to construct an object where some
>   attributes are passed to `initialize` or if you want to do something
>   other than simply calling `new` on your build class, you can override
>   the default behavior by defining `initialize_with` on your factory.

So you can replicate this:

```
obj = Project.new project_category: ProjectCategory.find(1)
```

within a factory by doing this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    project_category { ProjectCategory.find(1) }
    # ...

    initialize_with { new(project_category: project_category) }
  end
end
```

If you have lots of attributes and just want to pass them all into the `new` call, factory_bot has a shortcut:

```
initialize_with { new(attributes) }
```

All detailed at the documentation link above.